# Can a background app (with a location UIBackgroundMode) use a timer to poll a server every few hours?

Tags: ios

I have a background app with a UIBackgroundMode of location.

I would like my app to additionally contact a server every few or several hours to see if there is some new data for it (because using apple notification push would notify the user and that is not desirable).

Polling is something I would never use on any other OS, but with iOS they don't leave you much choice if there is certain functionality you would like to try to achieve.
If the polling interval is quite lengthy such as a few or several hours between polls, and the polling activity itself only lasts several seconds then the usual knee-jerk reaction about it draining battery life is greatly diminished.

Would a repeating NSTimer fire when an app is in background mode? If not is there another type of timer or mechanism available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not allowed. You should have a look at Push Notifications and find a server side solution.

Comment: Thanks but I would like to download some content *before* notifying the user. So that once they are notified the content is ready and available for them to view, rather then them first being notified and then bring the app to the foreground and then wait while the app contacts the server and gets the data. But it seems this isn't going to be possible?

Comment: Not really, you can use the method applicationWillEnterForeground, like Robot Woods mentioned to prepare the data before the view is being loaded, but you should do it efficiently. This could be done without interrupting the "flow" of opening the App, if the data is small and your computations aren't as complex…

Answer (score 1):

If it's just to check for new content, and not really time sensitive, you COULD use the significantChanges background location method...but if the user stayed fairly immobile it'd rarely/never fire. I would probably also add the update check in applicationWillEnterForeground to be more sure